# MultiValueDictKeyError in sending an attachment

Tags: python, django

```
<script type="text/template" id="_escalation-container">
    <div class="response-container">
        <form action="" class="escalation-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                <a href="#" class="add-scripted-message">{% trans "Add Message" %}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-content-footer" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

I look at [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/) and tried to do what is written there.

View.py:

```
if request.POST:
    form = EscalationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        escalation_message = form.save(commit=False)
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        escalation_message.save()
```

And handle_uploaded_file is exactly the same;

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

EscalationForm.py:

```
class EscalationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EscalationMessage
```

and my model is:

```
class EscalationMessage(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='.')
```

Also, I added these into my settings.py;

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler"
]
```

However when I tried to send attachment it gave

```
File "/Users/mk/Documents/interaction/views.py", line 169, in create_escalation_message
    escalation_message.file = EscalationMessage(file=request.FILES['file'])
  File "/Users/mk/Documents/venvs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 322, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'file'"
```

I am new in web development and I am writing a mini-demo. I was trying to send a message with an attachment and I searched an example however, it gave this error. Do you have any idea about the error?

Thank you

Comment: I don't get it, your form in views.py is already a model form of model `EscalationMessage`, why do you do `escalation_message.file = EscalationMessage(...)`? Shouldn't the `file` field a `FileField`?

Comment: OK, it is wrong as you said but I cannot use "escalation_message.file = request.FILES['file']" this one as well. Because as far as I understand it is also the wrong way to handle the file so, is there a proper way to handle it?

Comment: I need to handle it because after this, I will send an email whose attachment is this file.

Answer (score 0):

File uploads must use `POST` method. Change your `form` tag to:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="escalation-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```